# jQuery - Select with :contains then change content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this code below and I am trying to add html before and after a span which has no id.

I can only select it with the `:contains` selector.
Using this selector, how can I add my elements?

```js
var tel = $('span:contains("+33 (0)1 02 03 04 05")');
var telText = tel.text();
var newTel = '<a href="#">' + telText + '</a>';
tel.html(newTel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js">
<span>phone number</span>
<span>+33 (0)1 02 03 04 05</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works here, you just have to use contains on the text that is inside the span.

```js
var tel = $('span:contains("+33 (0)1 02 03 04 05")');
var telText = tel.text();
var newTel = '<a href="#">' + telText + '</a>';
tel.html(newTel);

console.log(telText)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<span>phone number</span>
<span>+33 (0)1 02 03 04 05</span>
```